# Keeping the callback alive

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback

I have a callback that gets tossed around a lot. I can't figure a way to keep it through all of functions.

```
function a(callback) {
    callback();
}

var number = 0;

function b(callback) {
    number++;
    c(number, callback);
}

function c(number, callback) {
    if (number != 2) {
        a(function () {
            b();
        });
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}

a(function() {
    b(function() {
        console.log('hi');
    });
});
```

I need a way to get the outermost callback (the one with `console.log`) to the `a()` function and subsequently the `b()` function when I call the `a()` function in the `c()` function.

Let me know if this sounds like gibberish. I will try to clarify.

Comment: Can I ask why this needs to be done? It seems like you are getting close to what is known as 'callback hell' and you're going to want to avoid that at all costs. Also, you don't need to define an anonymous function each time you want to pass an already defined callback function. So you could simply do a(b(number, c))

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering a `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. This is because in `c` you're invoking `b` without passing any args so when `number !== 2` you've lost your reference

---

I re-wrote your code and it ended up working

```
var number = 0;

function invoke(fn) { // do you really need this? just invoke directly
    fn();
}

function count(fn) {
    ++number;
    limit(number, fn);
}

function limit(num, fn) {
    if (num < 2) // this is much safer
        invoke(function () {
            count(fn); // passing an arg here
        });
    else
        fn();
}

invoke(function () {
    count(function () {
        console.log('hello world');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting dangerously close to what is known as 'callback hell'. You'll want to avoid that if you can. Since I'm not 100% sure why you need to pass around so many callback functions, you can achieve what you're looking for by doing the following:

```
function increment(number, callback, callback2) {
    console.log('Incrementing number ' + number + ' by 1');
    number++;
    callback(number, increment, callback2);
}

function verify(number, callback, callback2) {
    if (number < 2) {
        callback(number, verify, callback2);
    } else {
        callback2();
    }
}

var number = 0;
increment(number, verify, function () {
    console.log('Hello world!');
});
```

You'll notice that I renamed some functions and excluded your a() function since it did nothing but execute the callback function passed to it. Unless that function is to serve another purpose, it is useless. You also don't need to create an anonymous function every time you are passing a callback. To pass a previously defined function as a parameter or callback, simply pass the function name without the (). If you are passing an undefined function as a callback, you will need to create the anonymous function which is what is being done with the console.log() callback.

Here's a jsfiddle. You can open your console log and see what it's doing.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9Lmgahy/)

Please also be sure to read up on callback hell and how to design your code in a way that it can be avoided. [Call back hell](http://callbackhell.com/)